# get basic SQL Server table structure information

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can get the number of columns in an SQL Server database with this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'Address'
```

But is there any way (for an unknown number of columns) I can get the name and datatype and length of each column?

Comment: What do you mean?. If you do a `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT COUNT(*)`, you get the column name, datatype, length and more information about the columns

Comment: You've already got the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table, what exactly isn't there?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Well, that just shows me the number of columns, not their names or datatypes or lengths.

Comment: @thomas - that's beacuse you're doing `COUNT(*)`; see Lamak's comment.  You may want to brush up on your SQL, since that's kind of basic SELECT knowledge, no offense.

Comment: @thomas but, as I said before, if you use `SELECT *`, then you do get all that other information

Comment: @Lamak Okay. That was copy/pasted from an SO answer. I didn't know that removing count would give me all this wonderful information. Thank you!

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables no worries. I use it so infrequently that a reminder to do some brushing up is probably the most helpful advice you could give :)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Instead of using `count(*)` you can `SELECT *` and you will return all of the details that you want including `data_type`:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'Address'
```

MSDN Docs on [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx)

Comment: yes, this is precisely what I needed. Do there exist any functions for turning the information returned by this into a statement which creates an identical table? Thank you.

Comment: @thomas You could use dynamic sql and generate a sql string that could be executed to create a new table.

Comment: @thomas you could use something similar to the code in this sql fiddle demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24970/9

Answer (score 32):

[sp_help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187335%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) will give you a whole bunch of information about a table including the columns, keys and constraints.  For example, running

```
exec sp_help 'Address'
```

will give you information about Address.

Answer (score 4):

[Name and datatype:](https://github.com/tmmtsmith/SQLServer/blob/master/FindColumnTypes.sql)

```
USE OurDatabaseName
GO

SELECT 
    sc.name AS [Columne Name], 
    st1.name AS [User Type],
    st2.name AS [Base Type]
FROM dbo.syscolumns sc
    INNER JOIN dbo.systypes st1 ON st1.xusertype = sc.xusertype
    INNER JOIN dbo.systypes st2 ON st2.xusertype = sc.xtype
-- STEP TWO: Change OurTableName to the table name
WHERE sc.id = OBJECT_ID('OurTableName')
ORDER BY sc.colid
```

Or:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS ColumnName, DATA_TYPE AS DataType, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS CharacterLength
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'OurTableName'
```

Answer (score 4):

Write the table name in the query editor select the name and press Alt+F1 and it will bring all the information of the table.

Answer (score 0):

For total columns information use below syntax : 
Use "DBName"
go
Exec SP_Columns "TableName"

For total table information use below syntax : 
Use "DBName"
go
Exec SP_help "Table Name"

Answer (score 0):

You could use these functions:

```
sp_help TableName
sp_helptext ProcedureName
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.